# How to stop program from crashing while background scheduler is running?

Tags: python, opencv, apscheduler

I am drawing a face using opencv and then subsequently drawing a different face when a key is pressed ('s' for surprised face,'d' for sad face, 'a' for angry, etc.). I want my faces to simulate eyes blinking so I am using a background scheduler to run a blinking function every five seconds. The blinking function is part of a Blink class that knows what the current face is so when it 'blinks', it redraws the correct face. However, every time I switch faces, the program crashes and I have to force quit python. The blinking works fine until I switch faces.

I tried pausing the scheduler before redrawing the new face and then resuming it after, but that doesn't make a difference. It still crashes, and I can't figure out what else to try. The program switches the faces just fine. It only crashes when I add the background scheduler and the blinking.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 as cv
from drawCopy import*
import random
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import logging

class Blink:
    def __init__(self,currentFace,img,scheduler):
        self.currentFace = currentFace
        self.img = img
        self.scheduler = scheduler

    def blink(self):
        self.img[:] = backgroundColor
        blinkDict[self.currentFace](self.img)

    def addJob(self):
        self.blinkJob = self.scheduler.add_job(self.blink, 'interval', seconds=(random.uniform(3.0,5.0)),max_instances=2)

    def startSched(self):
        self.scheduler.start()

    def updateCurrentFace(self,newFace,newImg):
        self.currentFace = newFace
        self.img = newImg

blinkDict = {'n': blinkNeutral, 's': blinkSurprised, 'd': blinkSad, 'a': blinkAngry, 'h': blinkHappy}

logging.basicConfig()

img = np.zeros((600,1024,3), np.uint8)
img[:] = backgroundColor
cv.imshow('Face',img)

currentFace = cv.waitKey()
img = drawFace(img,chr(currentFace))
cv.imshow('Face',img)

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
blinkObj = Blink(chr(currentFace),img,scheduler)
blinkObj.addJob()
blinkObj.startSched()

#The code runs fine until here and then crashes when the next key is pressed

currentFace = cv.waitKey()
if currentFace == 27:
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    img[:] = backgroundColor
    img = drawFace(img,chr(currentFace))

    blinkObj.updateCurrentFace(chr(currentFace),img)

    cv.imshow('Face',img)
    cv.waitKey(0)

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You say _the program crashes_. Could you post the actual error messages and complete traceback?

Comment: No error message. When I run it and click a key to switch to the second face, the mouse turns into the rainbow loading symbol and it will just just sit like that forever until I force quit. After a few seconds it starts showing the following error which I figure it shows because it's unable to run the background scheduler function while in that frozen state: WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job "Blink.blink (trigger: interval[0:00:04.066840], next run at: 2019-05-15 21:21:45 MDT)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (2)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same code on a Linux machine (have been previously running it on a Macbook pro), and it worked just fine. I still don't know why it's crashing, but it appears to be a Mac or Macbook specific issue.